# Javascript function updates html field then erases it

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe a stupid question but i do not know the root cause of this strange javascript behavior : my "submit button" calls a "javascript function" which 
updates a html field (ok), then erases it (nok) !
Why the "demo" field is erased after execution ??
(Maybe one of the easiest question of stackoverflow ever!)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<form>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit"
          onClick="launchSubmit()">Submit
  </button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function launchSubmit(){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "bla bla bla"; 
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaScript doesn't erase the value... the subsequent posting back of your form does. You put `type="submit"` in your button which will submit the form to the server. This then causes the server to send back a fresh copy of the HTML page for the browser to use. Of course the fresh copy does not contain any changes made by JavaScript, since those only exist in the browser's old copy of the page, which is now destroyed.

You can change it to `type="button"` and it won't post back the form. If you don't actually need a form here, then remove the `<form></form>` tags as well.

Here is some useful background reading about forms: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms

Comment: As an addition, you can also use `event.preventDefault()` in the function, so that it does not submit the form.

Comment: @Refilon true, but why use extra code when you can just use the attributes of the HTML itself?

Comment: Sometimes people can not edit the html, so removing a form is maybe not possible. Then the `event.preventDefault()` will do the trick. Also if you need the form data in jQuery, this will be the best way to go.

Comment: @ADyson It really doesn't matter, I think. It all depends on what you prefer.

Comment: @Refilon " Also if you need the form data in jQuery, this will be the best way to go" ...whether you use the button type, or preventDefault, or return false or anything else will make no difference to that whatsoever.

Comment: It makes a difference, because it's easier. But no problem if you don't want to add it in your question. I'm not here to argue, I'm here to help.

Comment: @Refilon me too. But part of helping is challenging assertions which have no particular evidence. How exactly do you think it's "easier" to get form data because preventDefault() was used to stop the postback? How you stop the postback has nothing to do with how you use JS/jQuery to get the form data. They are two totally separate tasks. Can you justify your statement (perhaps with an example)?

Comment: If you do not use `event.preventDefault()` the form will be submitted and the data will be gone. If you use the button like you said, you will have to remove the form, so you can not use `$('form').serialize()`, and you will have to target every input type individually. That's why I said it's easier.

Comment: @Refilon "If you use the button like you said, you will have to remove the form" ...no, that's not true at all. In my answer I mentioned removing the form as an optional extra, since the form in the question contains no input fields, but it's certainly not necessary in order for the `type="button"` change to work. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v3ya5g9f/

Comment: Sigh... I don't know how to explain it anymore. Your method works, but you're not really getting what I mean, so I'm not going to explain it to you any further. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Refilon I'm not getting what you mean because it has no basis. The thing you stated as your reason for it being "easier" was factually incorrect. So naturally I don't see your point. If you have another reason then please go ahead with it - it's an interesting discussion. But what _is_ factually correct is that getting the form data and stopping the postback are separate tasks. Using one particular way of stopping the postback (apart from simply removing form tags entirely) has no impact on your ability to retrieve the form data subsequently. I hope you have a nice day too.

Answer (score 3):

That is because your button type is set to `submit`. Setting this to `button` will keep the value on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

When you click submit button, it submitted the form. Then you see a new empty page.

You should add a `return false` to `onclick` event, or you can change the `type=submit` attribute to `type=button` to make a normal button.

Use inline `onclick` is a bad idea, which may cause bugs if you do not take care of the escaping/returning, etc. , you had better use some libraries like `jQuery`, it will help you much more.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<form>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit"
          onClick="launchSubmit(); return false;">Submit
  </button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function launchSubmit(){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "bla bla bla"; 
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The `jQuery` version:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <head></head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<form>
  <button id="the-button">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#the-button').on('click', function() {
        $('#demo').text('hello world');
        return false;
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how would jQuery help with this very simple problem?? That's a totally irrelevant piece of opinion. (I like jQuery but it has nothing to do with this question)

Comment: @ADyson I have answered your problem in the first paragraph and give you an example based on your question. Use inline `onclick` is a bad idea, which may cause bugs if you do not take care of the escaping/returning, etc.

Comment: You seem to have mistaken me for the person who asked the question...take a closer look at the IDs of the people you are talking to.

Comment: P.S. You don't need to turn to jQuery just to remove inline "onclick" handlers etc. `document.addEventListener` will do the job, with no 3rd party code required. And jQuery isn't a framework, it's just a library. And fear of bugs isn't the reason people advise not to use inline event handlers...separation of concerns / better maintainability is the motivation.

Answer (score 0):

Because your form updates that element `id="demo` and then submits. In order  to make that element remain, you must prevent the form from submitting.

Please Note:

> An html form will always submit event when the action is not provided.
>   When you submit without the action, it submits to the same page, more
>   like reloading but with form data in memory.

So this is how you could approach your problem:

```js
function launchSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "bla bla bla"; 
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<form name="form">
  <button type="submit" value="Submit"
          onClick="launchSubmit(event)">Submit
  </button>
</form>
```